# Assign Super Key for Show Applications

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 18.10, the shortcut for showing applications is Super+A. Is there any possibility to assign Super alone for that? I tried from the settings-keyboard shortcuts, but it asks for a combination of Super+some-other-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The original answer relies on `xcape` or `ksuperkey`, tools that work on Xorg only. Users on more recent versions of Ubuntu (Gnome Shell 40 and up) can use the extension [Start Overlay in Application View](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5040/start-overlay-in-application-view/) by Hex_cz to have <kbd>Super</kbd> show applications rather than the overview.

**(Previous answer) Xorg only**

You can do so by reassigning releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key alone to a specific shortcut. For this, you need an additional little tool such as `xcape`(available by default in the Ubuntu repositories) or `ksuperkey`.

1. First, disable the existing binding of <kbd>Super</kbd>:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
   ```
2. Then, have the tool to redirect pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> autostart during login with the following command:

   ```
   xcape -e "Super_L=Super_L|a"
   ```

   As <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> triggers the application overview, this command will trigger that binding if you press and release <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Comment: This does not work in Ubuntu 22.10. Not sure if it worked for any other versions after 18.10 either.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ indeed `xcape` and `ksuperkey` only work on Xorg. On 22.04 and up, Wayland has become the default.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ there is now an extension. I updated my answer.