# Can I add to the Super key/Applications search sources?

Tags: search

I like the current function of the Super key with Ubuntu 19.04, but I would like it even more if it would also search for files. Essentially I would like it to generate the results of 'locate xxx' along with the results it already gives. Is there any way to do this?

If not, what about an alternative program that does the same thing (much like voidtools Everything for Windows) that I could map to the Super key?

Answer (score 2):

First, Gnome Shell, and certainly in Gnome 19.04, should correctly find file names in your home folder. Make sure that, in "Settings" - "Search", "Files" is turned on. It will, by default, only search your Home folder. Clicking the cog wheel below allows you to add other search places. Avoid indexing too much of files, because there is a performance cost.

In Gnome shell, additional search sources can be added as "[Search Providers](https://developer.gnome.org/SearchProvider/)". Several search providers come with Gnome Shell. You can toggle them on or of in "Settings" - "Search". Third party search providers are typically installed through a Gnome Shell extension. For example, a [YouTube Search Provider extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1457/youtube-search-provider/) can be installed from the Gnome Shell Extensions website. To add your own search provider would require some technical programming skills for coding a custom extension.

Alternatively, you could consider a keyboard launcher such as [Albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) or [Ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/). These provide a range of plugins to extend their capability beyond that of quickly launching an application. None of these launchers is included in the standard Ubuntu repositories, but they can be conveniently installed using either .deb files or a repository.

With some bash knowledge, you can go a long way with menu systems such as "[dmenu](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/)" or "[rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi)". These are desktop independent menu systems running on plain X. You can feed them the output of any script, in any programming language, and they will present the choices in a very efficient menu, where typing some parts narrows the choices very quickly down to the item you want. These powerful tools are commonly used in lightweight windowmanager-only setups (openbox, tiling window managers such as i3).

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091877/assign-super-key-for-show-applications/1180797#1180797) on how to map another command to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Comment: This is a great answer but it didn't obviously work for me. I went to Settings->Search->Files is checked, and then clicking on the cog to see Search Locations, Home is checked. My home folder contains a git folder with several repos. But now, pressing the Super key and typing the name of a .java file that I know exists turns up nothing. Is this kind of search supposed to work? Should I look into a search provider extension?

Comment: That is probably Gnome Tracker still being broken. Indeed, it is designed to find contents into files, but fails to find existing files. I taught that would have been improved in 19.04